# Cast from List to SelectListItem

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I need to cast a list that i get from DB to `SelectListItem` so as to display it dropdown list I have tried the following code

```
public List<SelectListItem> Liste_proprietaire()
{
    List<SelectListItem> selectList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    var maListe = (from p in db.reqopt
                   where (p.categorie.Contains("proprietaire"))
                   select new
                   {
                       str = p.valeur
                   }).ToList();

    foreach (var x in maListe)
    {
        selectList.Add(x);
    }

    return selectList;
}
```

they give me an error under `selectList.Add(x)` telling that function `Add` has invalid arguments.

Comment: did you take a look to see what the Add method takes as an argument in the selectList object? I suggest you take a closer look ;)

Comment: You sould parse your maListe's objects to `SelectListItem` type

Comment: Yes i now, but the question is how to cast it, i've tried that 
                selectList.Add((SelectListItem) x); but that doesnt work either

Comment: its not about casting here... take a look at what the Add method accepts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` is an instance of an anonymous class (created with `new { }`). You can't instantly convert that into a `SelectListItem`.

You could do that yourself though:

```
selectList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = x.str });
```

Or directly create `SelectListItem` items from the LINQ expression:

```
select new SelectListItem()
{
    Value = p.valeur
}
```

Comment: @Redadublex: You are very welcome. Note that using anonymous methods can be very nice, but you have to worry about casting. For everything that crosses methods, you should create regular types.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `SelectListItem` instead of `anonymous` type. Try this.

```
    public List<SelectListItem> Liste_proprietaire()
    {

        List<SelectListItem> selectList = new List<SelectListItem>();

        var maListe = (from p in db.reqopt
                       where (p.categorie.Contains("proprietaire"))

                       select new SelectListItem
                       {
                           Text = p.valeur,
                           Value = p.value //Put your value column here
                       }).ToList();


        foreach (var x in maListe)
        {
            selectList.Add(x);
        }

        return selectList;
    }
```

**Note**: You have to update the `Value` Property of the `SelectListItem` accordingly.

Comment: @Redadublex: Note you have the ability to upvote. I guess he wouldn't mind to see your token of appreciation :)